# How to show additional data in tooltip of PIE Chart-Highcharts

Tags: angular, highcharts, tooltip, angular-highcharts

Tying to add extra additional data in pie chart. I have tried in this way but not working. the value is not displaying in tooltip. So is it possible to add additional data in tooltip?.
chartData=[{"name": "apples", "y": 20,"additionalData": 33$},
{"name": "oranges", "y": 40,"additionalData": 20$},
{"name": "bananas", "y": 50,"additionalData": 10$}]

```
 Highcharts.chart('chartContainer', {
   chart: {
    // Edit chart spacing
     spacingBottom: 15,
     spacingTop: 10,
     spacingLeft: 0,
     spacingRight: 10,
     width: 600,
     height: 350
   },
   title: {
     text: ''
   },
   xAxis: {
     title: {
       text: null
     }
   },
   yAxis: {
     min: 0,
     title: {
       text: ''
    },
    labels: {
      overflow: 'justify'
    }
  },
  tooltip: {
    pointFormat:'<b>{point.y}<b><br> Cost: <b>{point.additionalData} </b>'
   },
  
   plotOptions: {
     pie: {
       allowPointSelect: true,
         cursor: 'pointer',
       dataLabels: {
         enabled: false
       },
        point:{
         events : {
         legendItemClick: function(e){
             e.preventDefault();
         }
        }
    },

      showInLegend: true
    },
  },
  credits: {
    enabled: false
  },
  series: [{
    colorByPoint: true,
    type: 'pie',
    data:this.chartData
  }]
})
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values you have in your additionalData property are numbers, but they include the euro symbol so you probably want to be using strings, otherwise you will have invalid json.

```
[{"name": "apples", "y": 20,"additionalData": "33$"},{"name": "oranges", "y": 40,"additionalData": "20$"},{"name": "bananas", "y": 50,"additionalData": "10$"}]
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0sacqubp/